# Game Theory: a player's payoff in a zero sum game

Tags: game-theory

I am wondering for a two person zero sum game, is it true that the maximum of a player 1's payoffs is always greater than or equal to zero? Will there be a case that all of the player 1's payoffs are negative and all of the player 2's payoffs are positive, more clearly, will the following payoff matrix for player 1 and player 2 exist?
$$\begin{bmatrix}(-1,1)\space(-1,1)\\(-1,1)\space(-1,1) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I'm not really familiar with game theory, but how could the maximum payoff be negative?

Comment: @Leo Li Do you mean the maximum of all of the player's payoffs?

Comment: @TobyMak yes like the maximum of player 1's payoffs

Comment: Who is player 1?

Comment: @Leo Li Be much more clear in specifying what your question is next time. If someone who's going to answer your question doesn't know what the question even is, how do you expect them to try to answer it?

Comment: @LeoLi Ok you can't just *completely* change the question. (from Toby Mak's earlier comments I gather it's not even the first time).

Answer (score 0):

*Does the following payoff matrix exist*? Well, you wrote it down, didn't you? That looks like a (very boring) zero sum game to me, where one player always loses a buck and the other player always wins a buck.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of zero-sum game is a game which the reward/lost comes only from the players, let's say the reward is money, if all the money of the game comes from the players it is a zero-sum game. So the player which the absolute reward is leaning onto is not important. Because in this situation when creating a matrix of the game the absolute value of the 2 parts in each place if the matrix will be equal than a lot of ppl write only the amount of money player 2 gives player one, and if player one gives money to player two in all possible outcomes it will be looks like this: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
Ofc the $-1$ can be any value.